# Error ckan.lib.search.common HTTP code=404

Tags: solr, ckan

I have a solr instance up and running and I can visit the solr admin page without any problem. I have setup a solr multicore with one core for ckan and another core for a different application. I can see two different collections as well in the admin page. I don't understand why ckan is not able to connect to Solr. I have even include solr site url in production.ini.

ckan.lib.search Problems were found while connecting to the SOLR server

Edit # 1: I have installed ckan from Source; I already had Solr running so all I did was added a new core & collection for ckan in an existing solr instance

Comment: We need more information. At what URL can you visit the Solr admin page in your web browser? What schemas do you see in the Solar admin page? Do you for example have the ckan version 2.0 schema at this URL: <http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckan-schema-2.0/admin/file/?contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&file=schema.xml>? And what is the `solr_url` setting in your config file?

Comment: I can visit Solr admin page at http://localhost:8983/solr/#/. I have two collections - collection1 (for a different application), ckancollection (for ckan). Yes, I can see the schema from the solr admin page http://localhost:8983/solr/#/ckancollection/schema.

Comment: the solr_url in my config file is http://localhost:8983/solr/ckancollection/

Comment: Do you get CKAN's `schema.xml` file if you visit http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/ckancollection/admin/file/?contentType=text/xml;charset=utf-8&file=schema.xml ?